# Escape velocity

Tags: physics

Calculate the escape velocity from a white dwarf and a neutron star. Assume that both the white dwarf and the neutron star is 1 solar mass. Let the white dwarf’s radius be $10^{4}$ kilometres and the neutron star’s radius be 10 kilometres.

> escape velocity $= \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{R}}$
>
> > '**G**' is gravitational constant (6.733 minus ¹¹) 
> >     '**M**' is mass 
> >     '**R**' is radius

So I tried inserting the values for the white dwarf where in

> **R** is $10^{4}$ **G** is $6.67\times10^{-11}$ and **M** is 1 because 1 solar mass
>
> > **and the answer is $1.15\times10^{-9}$**

I'm pretty not that much sure if I answered this one correctly or not, because I'm in doubt with the 1 solar mass that I've got, do I still need to convert some things in here?

Comment: 1 solar mass is the mass of our sun ($1.989 \times 10^{30}$kg) not the number 1

Comment: This question is not well worded. For example, "Assume that each (what??) 1 solar mass" and "let the white dwarf's radius be (how many???) kilometers"

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen sorry just edited it, i have a weak internet connection right now

Comment: @Dan so it would be like this ? $\sqrt{\frac{2(\left ( 6.67x10^{-11} \right ) (1.989×103^{30}))}{10^{4}}}$

Comment: Yes $\quad\quad$

Comment: It seems to me that you made something strange with units. Have you transformed all the data in international units? (meters, kg, ...)

Comment: @seoanes The units that I've used is still the ones for the **G** which is N.m^2/kg^2 **R** which is Km and **M** which is Kg

Comment: Although now you just have to be careful about the two radii, one is ten thousand km while the other is only 10

Comment: @Dan should I still convert the units for it?

Comment: @user325861 the radious has to be written in meters, in order to be consistent with the units of $G$

Comment: Yes because the gravitational constant is in Newtons squared meter per square kilogram

Comment: so the 10 km would become 10,000 m and the 10^{4} would be 10,000,000 m ? am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issue here is not math, it is units. Your equation for escape velocity seems to be correct, as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity).

$$v_\text{escape}=\sqrt{2GM \over R}=\sqrt{{2\left(6.674\times 10^{-11} {\text{m}^3\over{\text{kg}\cdot s^2}}\right)\left(1 M_{\odot} \right)}\over{\left(1\times 10^4 \text{ km}=1\times10^7 \text{ m}\right)}}$$
This converts to:
$$3.653\times 10^{-9} \sqrt{\mathbf{{m^3 M_{\odot}}\over{\text{m}\cdot \text{kg} \cdot \text{s}^2}}}$$
This is technically correct, but we can convert solar mass ($M_\odot$) to $\text{kg}$ by the following conversion: $1 M_\odot = 1.989\times 10^{30} \text{ kg}$.

Note that we will multiply the number by the square root of the relationship, since we factored out the square root. So the final answer is:
$$5.152\times 10^6 \sqrt{\mathbf{\text{m}^2 \over \text{s}^2}}$$
$$5.152\times 10^{6} \mathbf{m\over{s}}$$

Comment: I think the result is of the order of $\sim10^6 m/s$. Are you sure about the substitution of the solar mass?

Comment: I think you made an error: the proportionality constant between the solar mass and kg should be square rooted, so the result should be on the order of $10^{-9+15}=10^6$. (Possibly $10^7$, since the original number was almost on the order of $10^{-8}$.)

Comment: I was fixing that as you guys were commenting. Good catch! I also misinterpreted $10^4$ as *m* instead of *$10^4 km$*. That's been fixed too.

Comment: @FundThemCalculus wait shouldn't be the formula is $\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{R}}$

Comment: Yup, fixing that too.

Comment: @FundThmCalculus advance thank you !!

Comment: @FundThmCalculus another question i tried doing it on calculator I got the answer of **5152588.864 m/s**

Comment: That's what I got too, so no worries there:$5,152,589=5.153\times 10^6$, which is within roundoff of my original answer. The relative difference is about one thousandth of a percent.

Comment: @FundThmCalculus oh thank you, so for the second one the neutron star problem i'll just follow the steps for it right?

Comment: Yup, exactly the same problem.